# Google Charts - bars stacked in front of one another (overlapped), rather than atop one another

Tags: charts, bar-chart, overlapping, stacked, google-barchart

I would like to create a vertical bar chart in which bars are stacked in front of one another (overlapped), rather than atop one another. With the height of each bar is its individual value, not its summed value.

As descriped here: [Image Charts per URL](https://developers.google.com/chart/image/docs/gallery/bar_charts)

Unfortunatly this function doesnt exist (IMHO) for charts created without URL, only the "stacked atop one another" version : [Visualization: Column Chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart)

Does anyone knows how to handle this?

Thanks a lot, Ben

Comment: I have an answer out there for this, but I couldn't immediately find it. can't remember what the other person called it. you might try searching my answers...

Comment: Do you mean this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53557106/relative-bar-chart-overlay-on-line-chart-in-chart-js
(use a second y-axis to give the bar series a different scale)
?
It's the closest i can find :)

Comment: no, I found the one I was thinking of, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49132688/5090771)...

Comment: even the question is useful for me, because i just have 2 datasets. thanks a lot!